# MySql: find rows from Table A not indicated in Tables B or C

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to take a set of ~5k Recipes and

1. remove the ones that **have not** been categorized
2. remove the ones that **have** been batched

This should leave me with a list of categorized, unbatched recipes.

I'm finding it hard to subtract records from an initial set, especially when each set is around 10k.  The queries I have been trying to use are either slow or returning results that I'm not confident in.  I'm just trying to get some answers on the numbers, so the query doesn't have to be particularly fast - reasonable will do.  These are the tables I'm using:

**Table recipes:** These are recipes that we are manipulating.  The ids are unique.

```
mysql> select id, title from recipes limit 10;
+---------+---------------------------------------------+
| id      | title                                       | 
+---------+---------------------------------------------+
| R162739 | Chipotle Steak                              |
| R223652 | Sweet Pea Mash on Toast                     |
| R216897 | Horchata Latte                              |
| R125550 | Roasted Beet and Fennel Salad               |
| R196267 | Sweet Potatoes with Fruit                   |
| R215630 | Mini Oatmeal-Raisin Cookies                 |
| R219133 | Pork with Butternut Squash                  |
| R166935 | Herb-Ginger Bulgur                          |
| R208872 | Chocolate-Macadamia Dreams                  |
| R220442 | Smoked Turkey Salad                         |
+---------+---------------------------------------------+
```

**Table recipe_log**: Each time someone adds a recipe to a category, a note is made in the log table. The log table has about 14k records - many of which are not the type I am interested in. Ids are not unique - the same recipe id may have many records.

```
 mysql> select * from recipe_log where type='category changes' limit 10;
+---------+---------------------+------------------+------+
| id      | date                | type             | note |
+---------+---------------------+------------------+------+
| R216064 | 2014-05-23 19:05:47 | category changes | NULL |
| R216064 | 2014-05-23 19:06:11 | category changes | NULL |
| R178159 | 2014-05-23 21:55:08 | category changes | NULL |
| R178159 | 2014-05-24 02:13:34 | category changes | NULL |
| R178159 | 2014-05-24 21:49:20 | category changes | NULL |
| r178159 | 2014-05-24 21:52:52 | category changes | NULL |
| r178613 | 2014-05-24 21:58:07 | category changes | NULL |
| r178613 | 2014-05-24 21:59:24 | category changes | NULL |
| r178159 | 2014-05-24 22:00:11 | category changes | NULL |
| r178613 | 2014-05-24 22:00:51 | category changes | NULL |
+---------+---------------------+------------------+------+
```

**Table recipe_batches**: This table contains recipes that have already been added to a batch.  Ids are not unique - the same recipe may be added to more than one batch.  There are about 10 records in this table.

```
mysql> select recipe_id, batch_id, date from recipe_batches limit 10;
+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| recipe_id | batch_id | date                |
+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| R109651   | EH_1_250 | 2014-06-04 01:01:01 |
| R111068   | EH_1_250 | 2014-06-04 01:01:01 |
| R113500   | EH_1_250 | 2014-06-04 01:01:01 |
| R117349   | EH_1_250 | 2014-06-04 01:01:01 |
| R117494   | EH_1_250 | 2014-06-04 01:01:01 |
| R109648   | EH_1_250 | 2014-06-04 01:01:01 |
| R109652   | EH_1_250 | 2014-06-04 01:01:01 |
| R110440   | EH_1_250 | 2014-06-04 01:01:01 |
| R113004   | EH_1_250 | 2014-06-04 01:01:01 |
| R111068   | EH_1_250 | 2014-06-04 01:01:01 |
+-----------+----------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of recipe_id's by first get the list of one that are categorized since you want to keep them and remove the ones that have been batched. Unless I understood it wrong every recipe that has been categorized should be returned unless it is also in a batch.

```
select distinct a.recipe_id 
from recipe_log a 
where a.type='category changes'
and not exists (select * from recipe_batches b where a.recipe_id = b.recipe_id)
```

Comment: I'm definitely with your logic; get the ones that are categorized already and just delete the rest of the data from the other tables with that result.

Comment: yeah I'm not sure if he actually wants to run a DELETE or just get the list of IDs.

Comment: Yeah i see what you're saying, he says remove. I think we're working backwards, get the filtered ones first, then deal with the large ones, whereas for some reason he wants to start in the haystack and thin the pile down until he gets the needle.

Comment: Good point about starting with the categorized batch, that makes sense.  I was thinking about starting with all the recipes because that is where the majority of the fields I need are.  I assume there's nothing wrong with me joining the recipe table into the query, right? Like: `SELECT DISTINCT(a.recipe_id), r.title, r.image FROM recipe_log a JOIN recipes r ON r.id = a.id ...`

Comment: @JChao: correct, I don't want to delete anything - I just want to exclude some recipes from my query.

Comment: This query takes 24 seconds and when I refine it further (adding another 'where' condition to the last subquery: `..AND b.batch_type = 'QA'`) it croaks.  I didn't expect that to have such an impact..

Comment: Plz add you full query to the post.

Comment: @JChao: Sorry, I don't have one.